# How to logout from metamask account in reactjs using Ethereum

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, metamask, decentralized-applications

I am unable to disconnect from Metamask account. I am attaching the code snippet.

```js
export const logoutUser = () => {
    if (window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
        window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
            return () => window.ethereum.removeListener('accountsChanged', accounts);
        });    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you cannot log out of Metamask by web3 or Ethereum api. You have to manually disconnect Metamask.

`accountChanged` listener will just detect if Metamask connects to a different account.

Answer (score 1):

As of now we can't disconnect from Metamask from our app, but what developers do is to remove/add the information of that Metamask account in a variable inside that app by pressing the disconnect/connect button.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

function MetaMaskLogoutButton() {
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      if (window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
        // Requesting permission to disconnect the current account
        const permissions = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: 'wallet_requestPermissions',
          params: [
            {
              eth_accounts: {},
            },
          ],
        });

        // Checking if the user approved the disconnection
        const approvedPermission = permissions.find(
          (permission) =>
            permission.parentCapability === 'eth_accounts' &&
            permission.caveats.length === 0
        );

        if (approvedPermission) {
          // Disconnecting the current account
          await window.ethereum.request({
            method: 'wallet_requestAccounts',
            params: [
              {
                eth_accounts: {},
              },
            ],
          });
          alert('Successfully logged out');
        } else {
          alert('Logout canceled');
        }
      } else {
        alert('MetaMask is not installed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during logout:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleLogout}>
      Logout from MetaMask
    </button>
  );
}

export default MetaMaskLogoutButton;
```